# Ubuntu 20.04 - logitech group video conferencing system - don't work

Tags: drivers

This system is used for video conferencing and worked well on Ubuntu 18.04. Today, the system, after freezing, hardly recognized the camera, and the rest of the audio part (microphones, speaker) is not recognized ... The whole system is connected via the USB port. I hoped that this error would be quickly corrected, but apparently in vain ... This system is used in the educational process of the university for online conferences.
Someone can reach out to fix something in the kernel of the system or this is a bug of the Pulseaudio server ...

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer or motherboard, and tell me what make/model hardware is connected via the USB port. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: - alex@dell:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version 01.05.00
 - Notebook Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series, 4Gib,Intel® Core™ i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz   × 4, HAMD® Hainan / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2), hdd 1TB

Only connected via the USB port - logitech group video conferencing system.
https://secure.logitech.com/en-gb/product/conferencecam-group?crid=1689

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 and the Logitech Group.

Comment: @AlexGots I need the exact model of Dell Inspiron 15, 3xxx so I can check for BIOS updates.

Comment: @MPhil Answer the same questions as in my first comment, but be exact on your model #.

Comment: dmidecode 3.2 (dmidecode -t system)
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
 Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
 Product Name: Inspiron 15-3567
 Version: Not Specified
 Serial Number: 5FMWZD2
 UUID: 4c4c4544-0046-4d10-8057-b5c04f5a4432
 Wake-up Type: Power Switch
 SKU Number: 078C
 Family: Inspiron

Comment: I updated today BIOS (sudo dmidecode -s bios-version) - 2.13.0

Comment: Today - 10/05/2020 after the BIOS update, the error in recognition and operation Logitech group video conferencing system was not eliminated. Does anyone know what to do? How to apply for Linux support ???